# multiple image upload with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

i am trying to do multiple image upload with different file input with the following code

```
<input name="attachement[]" type="file">
<input name="attachement[]" type="file">
```

My codeigniter code is

```
$config = array(
                'upload_path' => $path,
                'max_size' => 1024 * 100,
                'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpeg|jpg|png',
                'overwrite' => true,
                'remove_spaces' => true);
            $images = array();
            $this->load->library('upload');

            $files = $_FILES;
            $count = count($_FILES[$attachName]['name']);


            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

                $_FILES[$attachName]['name'] = $files[$attachName]['name'][$i];
                $_FILES[$attachName]['type'] = $files[$attachName]['type'][$i];
                $_FILES[$attachName]['tmp_name'] = $files[$attachName]['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES[$attachName]['error'] = $files[$attachName]['error'][$i];
                $_FILES[$attachName]['size'] = $files[$attachName]['size'][$i];

                $fileName = $title . '_' . $_FILES[$attachName]['name'];
                $images[] = $fileName;
                $config['file_name'] = $fileName;

                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                $this->upload->do_upload();
                if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
                    $return['data'][] = $this->upload->data();
                    $return['status'] = "success";
                    $return['msg'] = sprintf($this->lang->line('success_item_added'), "Image", "uploaded");
                } else {
                    $return['status'] = 'danger';
                    $return['msg'] .= $this->upload->display_errors('', '') . "\r";
                }

            }
```

In the code above $attachName="attachement"

But i get error `You did not select any file to upload`

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem

```
$this->upload->do_upload(); <-- removed this line
```

i changed this line

```
if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
```

to this

```
if ($this->upload->do_upload($attachName)) {
```

I hope this helps someone

Thanks to those who downvoted without a comment or even why

Comment: Hi, i used $attachName, i am getting error like "Variable not found"....How to solve this.

Comment: $attachName is a variable, it is the name of the upload field in the form

Comment: Hi, i used my upload file name alone i dint used any variable. If i add 3 images means, only 1 image adding to db and the given folder, remaining two image was not adding. To see my code [click this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381465/how-to-add-multiple-files-in-codeigniter?noredirect=1#comment48853855_30381465).......please give me solution for this i am struggling for two days

Answer (score 0):

For multiple file selection and upload you have to use

```
 <input name="attachement[]" type="file" multiple>
```

Otherwise always it will choose one file and multiple file fileds with same will overwrite each other.

Comment: i do not need the mutiple in the tag

Comment: then you have to keep different name for each tags otherwise last will overwrite the all previous one. Which is happening with you.

Answer (score 0):

Please include `enctype="multipart/form-data`  this in your `<form>` tag as:

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input name="attachement[]" type="file">
       <input name="attachement[]" type="file">
    </form>
```