# How to add multiple files in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter  in my project, i am facing one problem while uploading multiple files to database. uploaded images was not moving to the particular folder. so my file was not saving in my database. i have attach my code below please find the below attachment and tell me what i am missing.
Thanks in advance.
Model:

```
public function myfunction(){
$config = array(
            'upload_path' => 'charity_gallery',
            'max_size' => 2000 * 2000,
            'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpeg|jpg|png',
            'overwrite' => true,
            'remove_spaces' => true);
    $images = array();
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $files = $_FILES;
    $count = count($_FILES['charity_image']['name']);
    echo $count;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

        $_FILES['charity_image']['name'] = $files['charity_image']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['charity_image']['type'] = $files['charity_image']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['charity_image']['tmp_name'] = $files['charity_image']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['charity_image']['error'] = $files['charity_image']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['charity_image']['size'] = $files['charity_image']['size'][$i];

        $fileName = $_FILES['charity_image']['name'];
        $images[] = $fileName;
        $config['file_name'] = $fileName;
        $imgName = 'charity_gallery/'.$fileName;
        //echo $imgName;
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        //echo "hello"."INSERT INTO `charity_gallery` (charity_id, image_name, created_on) VALUES ('$cid', '$imgName', '$createdOn')";
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('charity_image')) {
            echo "how"."INSERT INTO `charity_gallery` (charity_id, image_name, created_on) VALUES ('$cid', '$imgName', '$createdOn')";
            $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `charity_gallery` (charity_id, image_name, created_on) VALUES ('$cid', '$imgName', '$createdOn')");

        } 


    }
    $aff = $this->db->affected_rows();
    return $aff;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="control-group" style="padding:15px;">
                                <label class="control-label" for="basicinput" style="padding:10px;">Image Gallery:</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <div class="input-append span6">
                                    <input type="file" class="span12" placeholder="Upload file" id="charity_image" name="charity_image[]" multiple>
                                </div>
                                <div class="span12" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                                    <output id="result" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
```

In this, If i add totally 3 images means only one image getting added and uploaded. remaining two image was not getting upload. I dont know where i am doing wrong.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No i dint get any error.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your path correct?

`'upload_path' => 'charity_gallery',`

Where is located this folder? Try `./charity_gallery/` instead. (make sure to have the correct permissions too)

Comment: If i add totally 3 images means only 1 image getting added and uploaded. remaining two image was not getting upload.

Comment: Try first without the insert into DB.... just for test if the upload part is correct.

Comment: I try the solution on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113832/multiple-files-upload-in-codeigniter and works for me!